# On the proof of "root test is stronger than ratio test"

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

It's known that root test is stronger than ratio test, it means whenever ratio test works, then so does root test, but the converse is not true, I've been looking for a proof and I found this paper:

[image]

---

I really cannot understand what's happened in the two last lines, how did the author conclude that:

$$\left(L-\epsilon\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{a_{N}}{\left(L-\epsilon\right)^{N}}<a_{n}<\left(L+\epsilon\right)^{n}\cdot\frac{a_{N}}{\left(L+\epsilon\right)^{N}}$$

and from this it's concluded :

$$\left(L-\epsilon\right)<\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}<\left(L+\epsilon\right)$$

Comment: Make (rename) $i:=n-N$ and $n:=N$.

Comment: The last line doesn't seem completely true, (maybe I am missing something). But what you should do is take the n-th root and then take $n$ very big, note that $a_N/(L-\epsilon)^N$ is fixed, so you can take its n-th root arbitrarily close to 1, for $n$ sufficiently large enough.

Answer (score 1):

The last line doesn't seem correct. What we have is that 
$$(L-\epsilon)\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_N}{(L-\epsilon)^N}}<\sqrt[n]{a_n}<(L+\epsilon)\sqrt[n]{\frac{a_N}{(L+\epsilon)^N}}$$
So, taking $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, we get
$$L-\epsilon\leq \liminf\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq L+\epsilon.$$
Since this is true for all $\epsilon>0$, we conclude that $\liminf\sqrt[n]{a_n}= \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}=L$. Hence $\lim\sqrt[n]{a_n}=L$.

Comment: Just a question, how to do you know $L-\epsilon$ is greater than  $0$? since we are taking the nth root, I think there should be an absolute value

Comment: @user715522 absolute value won't help when $L-\epsilon$ equals zero. But I think one can always restrict attention to the case that $\epsilon < L$, though the author did not say so

Comment: Yeah that's some detial that the writer didn't explain, but such tiny that you don't write it (otherwise would be misleading). What happens is that we want to show the inequality above for any $\epsilon>0$ small enough, (so you can make $\epsilon<L$).